# What SPL Token Program should I use, Token or Token2022?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, spl-token-program

I would like to create my own SPL token. However, I'm not sure which program is the best one to use since Token2022 is very new.

Can you help me choose the best or right one?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your use case.

If you want to create a token that's widely supported in all ecosystem wallets, and you don't need one of the new *Token Extensions* that are powered by the new Token2022 program, it's probably best to use the older version of the Token program.

If you want to build a token with [any of these extensions](https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions) you will have to use the Token2022 program.